# Django Template filtered on clicked variable

Tags: django

Take the following Models:

```
class InsName(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name = "Insurer/Broker")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Development(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    logno = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    insurer = models.ForeignKey(InsName, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    Phase_status = (
    ('dev','Development'),
    ('review','Review')
)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=10,
    choices = Phase_status,
    default='review',
)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=350)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('development-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.id} ({self.insurer})'
```

I have a template that outputs a table of the Developments. What I want is when an `Insurer` is clicked it brings up a template of all the developments filtered for that selection.

I've been trying various things but I don't know how to get the variable `Insurer` name into the view:

```
def insurer_filter(request):
    insname = InsName.objects.filter(name = {{ value }})
    ins_name = Development.objects.filter(insurer = insname)
    return render(request, 'insurer_filter.html', context = ins_name)
```

Please forgive my dodgy coding (or any advice is helpful!). I am completely new to this and just finding my feet but I cant find any help on doing the above.

Current development list template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>My Developments</h1>
  {% if mydevs %}
  <table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Log Number</td>
        <td>Client</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for development in mydevs %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ development.get_absolute_url }}">{{development.logno}}</a></td>
        <td><a href="insurer_filter/?name={{ value }}">{{development.insurer}}</a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Then I guess my new insurer_filter template will be something like:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1><Value> Developments</h1>
  {% if ???%}
  <table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Log Number</td>
        <td>Client</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for development in wilsons %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ development.get_absolute_url }}">{{development.logno}}</a></td>
        <td>{{development.insurer}}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You want get `{{value }}` from html to view? Can you post html before call `def insurer_filter(request):`

Comment: How would I do that exactly?

Comment: where is your template ? show us your template.

Comment: what do you mean by "when Insurer is clicked" ? is insurer in your html ?

Comment: This is the template that shows all developments. From this i want the url where insurer name is output to link to a new template with that insurers filtered list. (added above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

urls.py:

```
url(r'insurer_filter/(?P<name>[A-Za-z]+)/$', views.insurer_filter),
```

views.py:

```
 def insurer_filter(request, name):
     insname = InsName.objects.filter(name = name)
     ins_name = Development.objects.filter(insurer = insname)
     return render(request, 'insurer_filter.html', context = ins_name)
```

Comment: @user1680260 Take a look at my answer it would let you get the name of the insurer from the template into the view.

Comment: Hi Ahtisham, thanks for this. How would I then navigate to the insurer_filter.html page? I've tried     <td><a href="ins_filter/">{{development.insurer}}</a></td> in the template

Comment: @user1680260 Do you want to navigate to `insurer_filter.html.page` from the `insurer_filter` view ? and did you tried my answer ? did it solved your problem ?

Comment: Hi Ahtisham, thanks I've figured this out now using the code you supplied. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to have a basic view which returns a list of all developments with option to filter developments by insurer.

You can start with your view:

```
def developments_list(request):
    if request.GET.get('insurer_id'):
        # Check if we need to filter developments by insurer
        developments = Development.objects.filter(insurer__pk=request.GET.get('insurer_id'))
    else:
        # otherwise return all developments records
        developments = Development.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'developments_list.html', context={'developments': developments})
```

In your urls.py

```
from my_views import developments_list

path('developments/', developments_list, name='developments')
```

In your template you can have links for each of your Developments records:

```
{% for d in developments %}
<a href="{% url 'my_views:developments' %}?insurer_id={{ d.insurer.pk }}">{{ d.id }} {{ d.insurer.name }}</a> | 
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see above we are passing insurers ID in order to filter records by insurer.

Also you can place a link to reset your filter:

```
<a href="{% url 'my_views:developments' %}">Reset filter</a>
```

That is very simple way to solve your problem, also you can use Class Based Views in order to your views look more elegant.